# return the nearest number value above current cell within a list in Excel 2010

Tags: excel

This is a little difficult to explain but I have a list of data, all in one column, that contains a department number and then below each department number is a long list of brands that correspond to that department number.  So within this list there are multiple departments with brands listed underneath them.

My goal is to somehow return the value of the department next to each brand but because the department number is located above the list of brands and the data is changing each time I repull the report, the row numbers will not remain them same and there may be duplicate brand names, and I cannot figure out what formula to use because it is all contained in one column.

I need to come up with some type of formula that doesn't just search, but returns the value of the next number or value above the current cell and skips all of the text or blanks in between so it will grab the department number above it.  Is there a way to do this or a better way to accomplish the goal of assigning each brand to the department above it while allowing for changing data each time I pull the report?

I tried replacing all of the text with 0's or blanks and then used the indirect function to say: `=IF(BG24="",INDIRECT("BF" & ROW() - 1),"")`, but I assumed it would continue to loop and skip the zeroes or blanks until it found a number, but it did not, it just returned the zero value.

Comment: How is this set up? Do you have the name of the department, a list of brands, and the a gap (a few blank rows) before the next department and its brands? That is, is the department the first value, always followed by it brands? Or perhaps you have a known list of departments that you can store in another column and refer to? BTW Your post would be easier to read if you used paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, the following formula should do it. Put it in cell B2. In cell A1, I'm assuming that there's the department number.

```
=IF(ISERROR(A1*1), IF(ISERROR(A2*1), B1, ""), A1)
```

This will work for a table like the following where no brands are numbers only:

```
1
Brand1
Brand2
2
Brand1
Brand2
```

To become:

```
1
Brand1   1
Brand2   1
2
Brand1   2
Brand2   2
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, that worked perfectly!  I am not quite sure how it works, I am trying understand it and walk myself through what it is actually doing but I can't thank you enough, that is so great! Thank you!

Comment: The core formula relies on the fact that department numbers are numbers and brands are texts. A text times 1 gives an error in excel, and `ISERROR()` is perfect for that. So, if cell `A1` is a text, go to the next `IF()`, otherwise, take cell `A1`, being the dept number. The second `IF()` is a bit similar, but that's only to get the blanks when the formula is next to a number (dept num).